# Error displaying date using angularfire and firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble displaying a date (stored as Unix timestamp integer) from firebase using Angularfire.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="form-group"">
    <label for="message-followUp" class="control-label">Follow Up Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="message-followUp" ng-model="postToUpdate.followUp">
</div>
```

and the following controller:

```
 $scope.notePost = function (id) {
    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://firebase_url/Records/" + id);
    $scope.postToUpdate = $firebaseObject(firebaseObj);
};
```

Within the data returned I have a key called 'followUp' that contains the Unix timestamp. When displaying the html I get the following error:

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `1466773470397` to be a date

I was hoping I could wrap 'postToUpdate.followUp' in    new date() but that doesn't work

How do I convert the Unix timestamp to the correct date format (yyyy-MM-dd) so it displays without getting the error?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you go with `new Date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are retrieving from firebase is a string and the inux timestamp should be an Integer when passed to `new Date`.

### JS

```
$scope.notePost = function (id) {
    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://firebase_url/Records/" + id);
    $scope.postToUpdate = $firebaseObject(firebaseObj);
    $scope.postToUpdate.$loaded(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.date = new Date(parseInt(data.followUp));
        },
        function(error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    );
};
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group"">
    <label for="message-followUp" class="control-label">Follow Up Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="message-followUp" ng-model="date">
</div>
```

[Working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/72/).

Comment: Thanks, when i use $scope.date = new Date($scope.postToUpdate.followUp) and then console.log($scope.date) i get 'invalid date'

Comment: @Janbango Now I see what is your real problem. Updated the answer :). Take a look at the jsFiddle to see it working.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. I think it must be how I am trying to access the 'followUp' key from the firebase object as console.log($scope.postToUpdate.followUp) returns 'undefined'.

Comment: @Janbango take a look again. If it still not working. please set a jsFiddle

Comment: @Janbango Glad u made it! :)